# Bundle unix and win10

Tags: svelte, svelte-component

I have such a problem - when I create bundle under Unix, it will generate a bundle with lines like this:

> ```
> text2 = createText("\n\n");
> ```

And if under Windows:

> ```
> text2 = createText("\r\n\r\n");
> ```

But my CSS designer did so that it affects the appearance of the tree in the application.
Maybe someone will tell me how to get around this problem - for example, force Svelte to generate strings like:
     text2 = createText("\n\n");
Link to gitHub https://github.com/kirilletc/svelte.geomixer

Link to bundle line:
win bundle: https://github.com/kirilletc/svelte.geomixer/blob/master/public/winnie_2.0_win.js#L563
unix bundle: https://github.com/kirilletc/svelte.geomixer/blob/master/public/winnie_2.0.js#L563

It's compiled example:
windows:https://kirilletc.github.io/svelte.geomixer/public/index_win.html?config=N72NF
unix: https://kirilletc.github.io/svelte.geomixer/public/?config=N72NF

Comment: May I ask why your application need to know the difference between operating system line return ending?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline
It is an old documented issue

Comment: Svelte builder probably wants to know - because it inserts different strings in the JS bundle ...
But on the contrary, I would like Svelte to generate the same JS code regardless of the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is Windows - I just needed to convert all sources into Unix (LF) format without CR.
Just Svelte can not correctly handle files in the format of Win (CRLF)